# Find an Element in Protractor

Tags: protractor

```
 <div>
                <label localize="{data: 'Name', suffix: ':'}">Name:</label>
                <span class="required" ng-class="{'disabled': meterCreating}" input-control="{title: 'Meter', okCallback:setMeterName, value: meter.meterName, ss: 'meters'}">
                    <span hs-placeholder="Enter Name" class="ng-binding"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
```

What is the best way to find an element:  placeholder = "Enter Name"?

Scenario: find an element using Snippet above

User clicks on the "Enter Name" box, another windows pops-up for entering a name.

Answer (score 3):

Based off that HTML, the cleanest way I can see is by css chaining:

`element(by.css('span.required span.ng-binding'))` (would normally just be `span.ng-binding`, but I highly doubt that's unique.  I also doubt that `span.required span.ng-binding` is unique either)

There are many other options, however they won't be pretty cause they will be similar chains.

`element(by.cssContainingText('label', 'Name:')).element(by.css('span > span'))`;

or

`element(by.css('div label span.ng-binding'))` etc..

I would suggest asking your developers for better locators (specifically, ID's), it makes JavaScript way easier.  Unfortunately, I don't think you're able to locate that element by HTML attributes, which is one of my favorite ways.  It would have looked like this:

`element(by.css('span[placeholder=Enter Name]'))`  -- but I'm pretty sure that will throw an error for invalid locator.  It accepts most "standard" html attributes such as `value`, `option`, `style` etc...

Comment: @ Gunderson, your suspicion was right. The element was not found base on your suggestions. ( element no found)...                                                    
What are the best locators to find elements in protractor which has less possibility of being changed by developers so we would have a solid test case and less maintenance?

Comment: @Kevin `id` is the best by far because it is unique.  Xpath is the worst because it has high maintenance and runtime.  Anything inbetween (`css`, `model` etc) is personal preference in my opinion.

Comment: I tell my developers i don't care what the `id` is actually called, as long as it's there.  Even if it was `id="spanPlaceHolderEnterName"` - protractor will find that instantly with `element(by.id(...))` (and without problems like "more than one element found with..." errors)